# Using jQuery to call a PHP function on many elements one by one, not at once

Tags: php, loops, jquery, asynchronous

Let's say I use $.get to receive an array of user IDs.
Let us then presume that I want to go through all those user IDs (example: [13, 14, 15, 23, 34, 56]) and retrieve certain information on each, then populate a textfield based on the results, and move on to the next one.

```
$.each(array_of_users, function(i, id) {
    $.get("/somefunction", {id}, function(data){
         appendToField(data);
    }, "json");
});
```

How would I make it so that these loops don't all happen at once and then wait for the result together asynchronously, as they do now, but one by one? That is, I want to stop the loop from going onto the next element until the ajax requests says it's fine to do so.

What is the best way to approach this without using delays or timeouts, but actual responses from the function doing the processing?

Cheers

Edit:
The stylish representation of a "command-prompt" look is important to me, which is why I would like the textarea to receive messages one by one as the entries are processed. I am aware I could do this via PHP much easier and without the hassle or potential JS breaks, but I would like to do it stylishly via JS to simulate this "console" look, as in:

10:01:33: User 13 processed: Changed expiry date to 13.02.2011.
10:01:34: User 16 not processed: Target immune to system changes..
10:01:34: User 17 not processed: Target immune to system changes..
10:01:35: User 23 processed: Changed expiry date to 19.02.2011.
etc..

Edit2:

I just found this brilliant little plugin which lets me do exactly what I want. However, I cannot find the means to stop the queue once it's been started. This is now a new issue. Any ideas, anyone? Reloading the page works, naturally, but I would like it to freeze in place as soon as I hit the Stop button so that the user can simply copy the entire report right out of the textfield.

Comment: What about using the `async` property with `$.ajax()`?

Comment: @Saul: async doesn't let me stop the loop once it has started. Otherwise, yes, it accomplishes what I want it to, display and processing-wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, use the first `.get()` to retrieve the list of values (array_of_users). Using this list, pass them off to a "worker" function that takes the first element, works with it, then sends the remaining elements off to do the same. Keep going until there are no more entries to process. (think of it like a FIFO Queue)

```
$.get('/loadfunction',{},function(data){
  getinfo(data.array_of_users);
},'json');

function getInfo(array_of_users){
  if (array_of_users.length == 0)
    return;

  $.get('/somefunction',{array_of_users[0]},function(data){
    // handle the result of this id
    appendToField(data);

    // move on through the list, dropping the first element
    getInfo(array_of_users.slice(1));
  });
}
```

*EDIT: used variables / GET paths similar to what you mentioned in your initial question.*

Comment: While the jquery queue plugin accomplished what I wanted, I will take this as the best non-queue answer, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning an array numbers and then re-querying the server for more information for each id, why don't you return an array of objects? For example:

```
[
  {"id":1, "uname":"jsmith", "admin":true},
  {"id":2, "uname":"jdoe", "admin":false}
]
```

This is simple to do with PHP's [json_encode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function. When your JavaScript gets the array of objects, it will then have all of the data it needs for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Because I will have to process each "user" (in this example case), perform certain operations on the entity, and then return the status message of how the change went into the text field when the operation on the given user is done. Also, the number will sometimes go into tens of thousands which is why I want an interruptible one-by-one call, instead of one large instant call.

Comment: **@Swader** - for the reason you said you should do this check server side, so, let PHP process and wait untill everything is fine than display it with javascript via JSON.

Comment: @aSeptik: The stylish one-by-one population of the text area is important to me. I would like it to have a "console"-ish look, receiving messages one by one in a "command prompt" kind of way, as entries are processed one by one. Edited OP.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with jsummers... it would probably be better to pull all the info down at once instead of sending separate requests. With that said you could do what you want using `$.ajax` with `async: false`:

```
$.each(array_of_users, function(i, id) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/somefunction",
      data: {id: id},
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'get',
      async: false,
      success: function(data){
         appendToField(data);
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should process all in backend then return JSON like this:

```
    id: 2,
    user: 'mary',
    msg: 'Changed expiry date to 19.02.2011.'
},
{
    id: 3,
    user: 'marlon',
    msg: 'Something went wrong..'
},
```

> - DEMO 2 : http://jsbin.com/okudi4/4

Hi Swader.

premising that i have the same point of view of jsummers

here is the kind of effect you are looking for.

> - DEMO: http://jsbin.com/okudi4

```
$(function() {
    var results = ['brown', 'fox', 'jump', 'hover', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog'];
    $.each(results,function(i, item) {
        $('<li class="resultlistitem">').html(item).hide()
          .appendTo('#resultList').delay(i + '000').fadeIn(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, that is the effect I am trying to get, but not simulate it - actually produce it. I do not want to use delays, because I might need to process over 25000 entries at one point, and that is simply too much data. I want it to actually query the function and append the result for every user, but only after the result comes back. If user13 takes 0.3s to return "Changed fine" and user 15 takes 15 to return "Something went wrong" I want it to be shown that way.

Comment: I understand your view, and thanks for trying to convert me to it :) But I really can't afford to send an array of 25000 arrays in JSON format to Javascript just for the sake of displaying it. I want the user to have a parallel view of what's going on, which would let him react as soon as he sees an error. If I do it all in PHP and send back the results only, it's too late for all those other users. This way - as soon as a mistake is seen, the whole process can be stopped.

Comment: try to follow me, you say you have 25000 entry so you want make 25000 request to your database one-by-one, instead i say to do this job in one or two steps, let's say in two time first 12500 then other 12500... i think it will be more faster. keep in mind that JSON is made for this kind of job

Comment: I understand your point. This disables my user, however, from stopping the operation after noticing a problem for the first time. If users 1203-8990 are not going to be processed properly due to a miscalculation or error, my way would let the user stop the operation at user 1204. A pure-PHP batch processing operation would not, and would require the correction of a problem that is no longer there, but now looks completely differently. I will try your way as well, though, certainly, for performance's sake.